# how to convert from JSON to a parametric nested struct in julia?

Tags: json, type-conversion, julia

```
stringtest="""{ "struct_A": {
    "arg1": {
        "arg_B": 90
    },
    "arg2": 100
}
}"""

jsonDict=JSON.parse(stringtest)

struct struct_B<: myStruct
    arg
end
struct struct_A{T<:myStruct}
    arg1::T
    arg2
    function BatteryStorage{T}(arg1,arg2) where {T}

        return new{T}(arg1,arg2)
    end
end


to_struct=ToStruct.tostruct(struct_A,jsonDict)
```

why I'm always getting :

**LoadError: MethodError: no method matching struct_A(::Dict{String, Any})**

**caused by: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type
Dict{String, Any} to an object of type
struct_A
Closest candidates are:
convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T at essentials.jl:205**

Comment: Where is the `ToStruct.tostruct` function from? And how is it defined?

Comment: https://github.com/yubessy/ToStruct.jl ToStruct is a Pkg I used to convert from JSON to struct

Comment: did you try `to_struct = ToStruct.tostruct(struct_A{struct_B}, jsonDict)` ?